# web page link that can be opened in activity

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to be able to have a list of web site that when pressed thay open the link. but keep the app runing still so when the users is finished with the link he or she is still on the active page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an activity that inherits from WebView see Android [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), rather than say sending an intent with the full `http://` which delegates to the OS who is best to handle the intent which in the default case will be the web browser for the device. If you add a WebView then you are in control and when the activty ends it should return to the original Activity.

Comment: i do like the sound of that. i do look before i post question to see if i can find what am after but never can find just what am looking for. thank you

Comment: @Ravon If you want to manage the lifecycle of the user experience then you have to look at if the default intent handler can satisfy what you require, for instance sending an intent to use the default camera app is fine until the default app does not fulfil everything you want and this inevitably leads to rolling your own, good luck.

Comment: cheers. i just been reading above reference.  it sounds like what am after. webview and all but it would be ideal to open the page with a textview. but i will keep trying. and hopefully i post my resluts to help the mass.